# I'm confused about line-height and margins

Tags: html, css

When I design a page I try to keep things as balanced as possible. I want there to be an equal number of pixels separating each section, or in some cases, each element. With different font sizes and line-heights it's getting confusing.

To hopefully explain a little more clearly lets say I have a page like this:

```
<div class="intro">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse mattis tellus at neque posuere pellentesque. Donec dui purus, mattis ac consectetur rutrum, mollis id mauris. Curabitur placerat risus sed tellus condimentum, non viverra velit semper. In purus justo, ornare non mollis et, suscipit a diam. Quisque suscipit nisi lorem, eu interdum sapien rhoncus commodo. Donec quis blandit neque. Integer at aliquet dui. Etiam eu dolor feugiat, bibendum purus in, sodales sem.</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
   <h1>Heading goes here</h1>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse mattis tellus at neque posuere pellentesque. Donec dui purus, mattis ac consectetur rutrum, mollis id mauris. Curabitur placerat risus sed tellus condimentum, non viverra velit semper. In purus justo, ornare non mollis et, suscipit a diam. Quisque suscipit nisi lorem, eu interdum sapien rhoncus commodo. Donec quis blandit neque. Integer at aliquet dui. Etiam eu dolor feugiat, bibendum purus in, sodales sem.</p>
</div>
```

I want exactly 50px between the intro and content div. The p in intro has a a large line-height, causing extra pixels to be tacked onto the space between the divs. The heading in content also has a different line-height which adds pixels to the top of that. Putting a margin of 50px above content will be more than 50px thanks to the line-height. Whats the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of a modern web work flow, I might recommend you get comfortable with that lack of pixel precision, as it's going to come up a lot.

That said, if you really want that 50px exactly, it's all about math. Let's assume you're using relative units for line height.

```
.intro p {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

Now the math: 16 * 1.5 = 24px (line height)
24px - 16px = 8px (total space above and below the text after the text height is removed)
8px / 2 = 4px (space above OR below the text)

So to achieve exactly 50px of space, you might do something like this:

```
.intro {
    margin-bottom: 46px; // 50px - 4px of line height
}
```

Of course, you would also want to account for the line height of the first paragraph of text in the `.content` div as well.

Answer (score 0):

Look! Up in the Sky! This looks like a job for: CSS! You are right about that margin part. If you want to keep it simple try this:

In your content class:

```
.content {
  padding-top:50px;
}
```

And it's just that simple! Now it will push the content div down by 50px. Hope this is what you were looking for!